# How is the dot product of two cartesian unit vectors equal to the Kroencker delta?

Tags: vectors, kronecker-delta

In my lectures, the relationship $\underline{\hat{e_k}} \cdot \underline{\hat{ e_j}}$ is given to be equal to $\delta_{kj}$ - how is this so?

From my understanding this is equal to
$
\left(
\begin{array}\\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$, which would give $\left(
\begin{array}\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right)$; not the kroenecker delta.

For context, this is discussed whilst going over an introduction to the moment of inertia tensor.

Comment: The result of the dot product is a number, not a vector. In your example
$$\hat e_3\cdot\hat e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=0\cdot0+0\cdot1+1\cdot0 = 0=\delta_{32}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot product is a scalar, not a vector, so you are obvious wrong.

And then you seem to attach specific meanings to $k$ and $j$ when there are just used as variables in that statement.

$\underline{\hat{e_k}}$ (btw: that's an awful lot of indications it's a vector) just means the $k$'th unit vector, with that in mind try to calculate the dot product again.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I'd be presuming that $e_k$ was the same as $\underline{\hat{k}}$ - I'm taking this to mean that isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

The dot products is measuring *angles* between vectors. Especially, if $a$ and $b$ are unit vectors, then $a\cdot b=\cos\angle(a,b)$, where $\angle(a,b)$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$.

So the angle between the unit vector $e_i$ and $e_i$ is $0^\circ$ (because it's the same vector twice). Note that $\cos(0^\circ)=1$. Therefore

$$e_i\cdot e_i=\cos\angle(e_i,e_i)=\cos0^\circ=1=\delta_{ii}.$$

On the other hand, for $i\not=j$, the unit vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$ are perpendicular to each other (by definition). This means $\angle(e_i,e_j)=90^\circ$ and $\cos 90^\circ=0$. Therefore

$$e_i\cdot e_j=\cos\angle(e_i,e_j)=\cos 90^\circ=0=\delta_{ij}.$$

Comment: I would take $a\cdot b=\cos\angle(a,b)$ to be essentially the _definition_ of the angle between $a$ and $b$, so in particular $a\cdot b=0$ is the definition of "$a$ is perpendicular to $b$". If those are the definitions then this seems circular and/or incomplete: Saying that $e_j\cdot e_k=0$ because $e_j$ is perpendicular to $e_k$ is saying that the dot product equals zero because it equals zero. If otoh those are not the definitions you're using then what _is_ your definition of the angle between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I tried to provide intuition, not a proof. *Intuitvely*, the basis vectors $e_i$ are perpendicular to each other. To say they are "said to be perpendicular" because their dot product is zero will help no one who not already has understood dot products. You learn in school $a\cdot b=\cos\angle(a,b)$ as a theorem. In abstract linaer algebra you learn that we can generalize it the other way around in general linear spaces. To start with the latter one and assume this is helpful in a geometric context is IMHO a big didactical mistake. I would be glad if you reconsider the downvote.